# How to retrieve clipboard file pointer CF_HDROP

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, clipboard

Whenever we copy any file to `clipboard` using ctrl+c it stores file pointer for `cut,copy,paste` operation. Is there any way by which we can retrieve that file pointer using C#? I tried [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CF_HDROP) but didn't worked out for me.

My second question is how can we `perform paste operation` of file if we have its logical address? I am not able to find any valuable content that I can try.

Comment: Could you found a solution for this?

Comment: I've solved it, not by retrieving file pointer though. Check [Readers\FileDropReader.cs](https://github.com/undergroundwires/AsyncWindowsClipboard/blob/master/src/AsyncWindowsClipboard/Clipboard/Modifiers/Readers/FileDropListReader.cs) and [Writers\FileDropWriter.cs](https://github.com/undergroundwires/AsyncWindowsClipboard/blob/master/src/AsyncWindowsClipboard/Clipboard/Modifiers/Writers/FileDropListWriter.cs) at [AsyncWindowsClipboard](https://github.com/undergroundwires/AsyncWindowsClipboard)